# Let $f$ be twice differential function such that $f''(x)= -f(x)$ and $f''(x)=g(x)$.

Tags: functions

> **Problem**:Let $f$ be twice differential function such that $f''(x)= -f(x)$ and $f''(x)=g(x)$.
>
> If $h(x)=(f(x))^2 + (g(x))^2$ and $h(5)=3$. Find $h(10)$
>
> **Solution**:
>
> let $f(x)= asinx$
>
> $f''(x)= -asinx$
>
> $h(x) = 2 a^2 sin^2x$
>
> Now h(5) = 3
>
> So $\frac {3}{sin^25} = 2a^2$
>
> Hence $h(10) = \frac {3}{sin^25}* sin^210$
>
> $ = 3*4*cos^2 5 $
>
> $ = 1 (approximately)$

Is there any other method for solving this question ??

I mean other than taking example.

Comment: You just wrote $\;f''(x)=-f(x)=g(x)\;$ . Did you really mean this?

Comment: @DonAntonio It's far more plausible that OP mean $f'(x) = g(x)$, considering the equation that comes right after... but that's my guess.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah, same is given in the question

Comment: @rst : I hope you notice that $f''(x) = -f(x)$ implies that $f$ is infinitely differentiable! So assuming '$f$ is twice differentiable' is actually stronger in your context. :P

Comment: I think there's something fishy here: you say a(the) solution is $\;f(x)=\sin x\;$, but then $$h(x)=f(x)^2+(f''(x))^2\le 2$$ and it's impossible to get $\,3\,$ here...what's going on?

Comment: you can solve this as a differential equation

Comment: @DonAntonio Then we can try to solve this question by taking $f(x)=asinx$ where a is real number

Comment: Following up on DonAntonio's comment, another good solution is $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$, in which case also $h$ vanishes. You need to provide more information for the problem to be well-defined.

Comment: I agree, @rst, yet **you wrote** $\,\sin x\,$ is the solution...

Comment: @rst: Even in that case, you will still end up with multiple solutions. For example, both $a \sin(x)$ and $b\cos(x)$ give rise to solutions with $h(5) = 3$ by choosing $a$ and $b$ appropriately, but in those cases, $h(10)$ will have two different values.