# What is the value of $F (10) $

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

If $f''(x)=-f (x) $ , $g (x)=f'(x) $ and $F (x)=(f (x/2))^2+(g (x/2))^2$  and value of it at $x=5$ is $5$ then value of $F (10) $. From given conditions its known that $g'(x)=-f (x) $ . Then how to use  the condition of $F (5)=5$

Comment: $F$ is probably a constant function.

Comment: Yes it is one of the solutions  I also thought of it but how can we say that its the only solution from given conditions

Comment: $F(x)=5 \forall x$ is the only solution from the conditions precisely because $F'(x)=0 \forall x$.

Comment: I thought I had seen this before: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/427493/321264. (posed wrongly though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $F (x)=(f (x/2))^2+(g (x/2))^2$ then $F'(x)=f(x/2)f'(x/2)+g(x/2)g'(x/2)$ But $g(x)=f'(x)$ and $g'(x)=f''(x)=-f(x)$ combining these we get $F'(x)=0$ and F is constant function.

Comment: Minor pedantic note: a $1/2$ should appear when you use the chain rule. Of course this ends up not mattering since the result is zero.

Answer (score 1):

From $f''(x) = -f(x)$, we can tell that $f$ is of the form $C\sin(x) + D\cos(x)$, which makes $g(x) = C\cos(x) - D\sin(x)$.

Inserting into $F$, we get
$$
F(x) = (f(x/2))^2 + (g(x/2))^2 \\
= (C\sin(x/2) + D\cos(x/2))^2 + (C\cos(x/2) - D\sin(x/2))^2\\
= (C^2 + D^2)(\sin^2(x/2) + \cos^2(x/2)) = C^2 + D^2
$$
so $F(x)$ is constant, and therefore $F(10) = 5$.